# Scanning online directory using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

Given a directory on a website where the files all have the same substring (i.e. "aaa-") followed by a date and an Excel file extension, how would I use a regular expression to match one of those files.

For example, a file could be called `"aaa-2014_14_09.xlsx"` or `"aaa-2014_25_11.xlsx"`.

I've had a look over `C# regex` but as of now have not worked out a solution.

Comment: _"but as of now have not worked out a solution"_ - StackOverflow purpose is not to write this for you, but to help you with specific issues with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex but it won't check for the exact date.

```
\baaa-\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.xlsx\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/14)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for files in C:\

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("aaa-*.xlsx");
IEnumerable<string> matchingFiles = from f in files where Regex.Match(f.Name, @"aaa-\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.xlsx").Success select f.Name;
```